# Elegant way to use Android FileObserver on booting the device

Tags: android, boot, mount, fileobserver

I'm developing an application which starts automatically when the device boots and it needs to monitorize some special directories in the memory of the device, for this I use FileObservers, a snippet of my code is:

```
 if (folder == null)
    throw new FailedExecutionException(
            "Trying to check the limit of a null directory");

Log.d(TAG, "Setting a limit for " + folder.getAbsolutePath());

if (!folder.isDirectory())
    throw new FailedExecutionException(
            "FolderLimit should be checked on directories, "
                    + folder.getAbsolutePath() + " is not a directory");

    //Then create the FileObserver...
```

When I launch this application with the device running it works, the partition where is the folder that I'm observing is mounted and I can monitorize it, the problem is when I reboot the device, then this code is executed before the system mounts the partition and it doesn't recognize it as a folder:

```
com.mycompany.android.helpers.util.FailedExecutionException: FolderLimit should be checked on directories, /mnt/sdcard1/mycompany/photo/white_list is not a directory
```

Of course I can do some kind of `while(!created){ attempt() }` but I want to ask if there is a more elegant way to notify this application that the partitions are already mounted and the system is ready.

What I have if I execute mount in the shell is:

```
127|root@android:/ # mount | busybox grep sdcard1                              
/dev/block/vold/179:4 /mnt/sdcard1 vfat        rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime= 0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard1/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
```

Thank you

**EDIT** I forgot to say, I can't use Environment.getExternalStorage() for this, it is a modified device and this is a partition which is not guaranteed to be the external storage path in the release version

Comment: Elegant solutions and Android do not mix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did this by brute force...

```
private void attemptToCreateFolderLimit(final File file,
    final long limitCount, final long recycle) {

ThreadFactory.startNewThread(TAG, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < FOLDER_LIMIT_CREATION_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG,
            "creating folder limit for "
                + file.getAbsoluteFile());

        try {
        FolderLimit limit = new FolderLimit(file, limitCount,
            recycle);
        folderLimits.add(limit);
        } catch (FailedExecutionException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Limit not created");
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        try {
        Thread.sleep(FOLDER_LIMIT_TIME_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

    }
    }
});

}
```